# Cannot read property 'id' of undefined. Variable 'id' has coerced Null value for NonNull type 'ID!'

Tags: react-native, aws-appsync

I am using react native gifted chat and I am trying to figure out how to set _id, text, createdAt, userid, and name to the parameters of my mutation. I have been getting the following errors `variable id has coerced null value` or `cannot read property 'id' is undefined`. The main question I have is what to set messageid and messagetext to. I am using react native gifted chat with AWS.

```js
export const createMessage = `mutation createMessage($id: ID! $groupchatid: ID! $message: String! $createdUser: String! $createdTime: String!) {
    createMessage(input:{ id:$id groupchatid:$groupchatid, message:$message, createdUser: $createdUser createdTime: $createdTime}) {
      id
      groupchatid
      message
      createdUser
      createdTime
    }
}`;
```

````
    const user = Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
    this.setState({ username: user.username});
  }

  MessagesMutation = async () => {
    const AddMessage = { message: this.state.messages, createdUser: this.state.username, groupchatid: this.state.groupchatname };
    const newGroupChatMessage = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(createMessage, AddMessage));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(newGroupChatMessage));
  };


  componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({
      messages: [
        {
          _id: id,
          text: message,
          createdAt: new Date(),
          user: {
            _id: createdUser,
            name: createdUser,
            avatar: 'https://placeimg.com/140/140/any',

          },


        },
      ],
    })
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    const value = navigation.getParam('value')
    this.setState({groupchatname: value})
  }



  onSend(messages = []) {
    this.setState(previousState => ({
      messages: GiftedChat.append(previousState.messages, messages),
    }))
  }
  render(){
    const { groupchatname} = this.state;
  return (
      <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Header style={styles.headerColor}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>{groupchatname}</Text> 
        </Header>
        <GiftedChat
            messages={this.state.messages}
            renderUsernameOnMessage={true}
            onSend={messages => this.onSend(messages), this.MessagesMutation}
            user={{
            _id: this.user,
            name: this.user,
            avatar: 'https://placeimg.com/140/140/any'
            }}```
````

Answer (score 1):

You 've defined `id` as a parameter

```
createMessage($id: ID! $groupchatid: ID! $message: String! $createdUser: String! 
$createdTime: String!)
```

and have forgotten to pass an argument

```
const AddMessage = { 
 id:"valu...." //here
 message: this.state.messages, 
 createdUser: this.state.username,
 groupchatid: this.state.groupchatname 
     };
```

Comment: The question I have is what to set messageid and message text to. That is what I have been trying to figure out

Comment: first correct first issue `variable id has coerced null value`.next, do you work with amplify?

Comment: To correct that issue, I made id in my schema nullable. I removed the ! so Id in createMessageInput can be  null. But I am still getting the error that id is not defined. And yes I am working w/ amplify

Comment: with amplify, id is auto-generated so you can  remove id from mutation input, what's happening  in componentWillMount, is it before mutation or after, please attach full code,  it's not clear

Comment: I believe @Alex is right. You either need to provide the "id" variable in the AddMessage object or you need to change the query such that it does not expect a variable of type `ID!`. Changing the query signature to be to `mutation createMessage($groupchatid: ID! $message: String! $createdUser: String! $createdTime: String!) {
    createMessage(input:{ groupchatid:$groupchatid, message:$message, createdUser: $createdUser createdTime: $createdTime}) {
      id
      groupchatid
      message
      createdUser
      createdTime
    }
}` (e.g. remove the "id" refs) should do the trick.

Comment: I am getting a new error now which says "One or more parameter values were invalid. An Attribute value may not contain an empty string"